# analysis Methods

Tags: multiple-regression

I want to analyze following three of my research objectives,
•   Determine the position of women in the tourism and hospitality workforce as a diverse culture in an organization in four departments separately
•   Identify constraints that might affect for career progressions
•   Identify the strategies adopted by major enterprises in facilitating equality of opportunity and treatment for women
 what analysis methods do I want to use? regression or ANOVA?

Comment: Do you still need to collect your data or do you already have a dataset? If you do have a dataset, what are the pertinent variables to answer your questions ?

Answer (score 0):

None of these questions call for regression or ANOVA (which are the same method, really).

In fact, it's hard for me to see how they call for statistics at all.

Comment: When we face moderator decisions that are ambiguous or especially important, we usually discuss the issue in the moderator chat room, Peter. It is best not to act unilaterally, but to coordinate to ensure we are on the same page & making the best decision. Please join the ongoing discussion in the mod chat room at your earliest convenience today. I would like your input in the ongoing situation. Your perspective will help us come to the best strategy.